# TradingView using plotcandle, to color candle Wicks . But these Wicks still remain when chart is changed to line chart. How do i auto hide them?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, secure-trading

`TradingView` using `plotcandle` function, to color candle Wicks.

But these Wicks still remain when the chart is changed to line chart.

How to `auto-hide/disable` them when I change the chart type to line?

```
//@version=4
study("5 ema", overlay=true)

x = ema(close, 5)
x1 = sma(x, 5)

y = x >= x1
y1 = x <= x1

f_check() => high != 0 and open != 0 and low != 0 

red        =    color.new(color.red, 0)
green      =    color.new(color.green, 0)


f_red()     =>  f_check() ? color.new(color.red, 0)     : color.new(color.red, 100)
f_green()   =>  f_check() ? color.new(color.green, 0)   : color.new(color.green, 100)


f_wickcolor() => y ? f_green() : y1 ? f_red() : color.new(color.black, 0)

f_bordercolor() => color.new(color.black, 100) //f_wickcolor()


plotcandle( open, high, low, close, color = color.new(color.white, 100), wickcolor = f_wickcolor(), bordercolor = f_bordercolor(), display = display.all )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't as there is no method to detect which type has been selected from the toolbar using pine.

The only workaround is to set your chart to line and set the color to be fully transparent (invisible). Then code in your line/candle option manually and plot the full candle bodies and wicks or a line instead.

Comment: How exactly do i do that? In order to be transparent, the code has to detect first. How do I detect?

Comment: Please re read it carefully. Use the chart settings to set the line color to transparent.